# created jasper report is empty and no error is shown

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I'm using jasper reports in my application. And there is a service which create the report and a front-end request the report.

But when I download the PDF's are empty.

I tried to export it as an HTML document. The respond is like below for all scenarios.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
   <style type="text/css">
      a {text-decoration: none}
   </style>
   </head>
   <body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000">
   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr><td width="50%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center">

   <![if IE]>
   <script>
   var links = document.querySelectorAll('link.jrWebFont');
    setTimeout(function(){ if (links) { for (var i = 0; i < links.length;    i++) { links.item(i).href = links.item(i).href; } } }, 0);
   </script>
   <![endif]>
   </td><td width="50%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
       </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Seems like it's an empty html page also.

Why is this happening. I searched other similar answers but no luck.

Comment: My best guess would be that the underlying datasource does not return any data. In this case, by default jasper will return an empty document. This behavior can be configured. Look for the property 'whenNoDataType'.

Comment: seems like that's the issue. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports by default outputs an empty document in case the datasource does not return any data. This can be helpful, for example, to create subreports that are only visible in case there is also data for the subreport.

To control, how jasper will deal with empty datasources one can use the ** whenNoDataType** property. The different settings are

- **No Pages** (default) Jasper returns an empty document
- **Blank Page** Jasper returns a document with one blank page
- **All Sections No Detail** Jasper renders the entire report skipping the details band.
- **No Data Section** Jasper renders only the **No Data** band. Note that this, by default is not part of a report and needs to be added to use this option.